# SharePoint links are changed on save

Tags: navigation, url, top-link-bar

We have two SharePoint collections (Intranet and tfs).

Within the Intranet we can create links to the tfs Portal. However, within the tfs Portal, if we create a link back to the Intranet it gets changed.

For example:

We want to create an a Link from tfs to intra.abc.com
We create the link by editing the Top Link Bar or by editing though Quick Launch.

We enter the link intra.abc.com and click OK.
When we try to use the link it has been changed to tfs.abc.com

How do we allow the tfs site to create links without changing the URL?

Comment: Please provide the versions of SharePoint and TFS

Comment: both SharePoint collections are 2013

Comment: Are you tried with URL `https://intra.abc.com` or `http://intra.abc.com`?

Comment: tried both with the same result. intra.abc.com is always changed to tfs.abc.com